# Retrieve $_POST data submitted from external URL in WordPress(NOT API)

Tags: php, plugin-development, functions, customization

How can I retrieve `$_POST` data in the WordPress environment that comes from my external application(native PHP)? The external application was submitting a form and redirect it to WordPress.

To be more specific, I am working on integrating my WordPress site with another application that has my user database and would like to create something like **login with XXX**. So I wanted to retrieve the `$_POST` data that submitted from that application into my WordPress and manage the authentication from WordPress.

I tried to print `$_POST` inside my themes `functions.php`, it does not show the data at all. I even try with `$_REQUEST` but to no avail.

I won't be able to use `wp_remote_post` because there's no URL to be used in arguments and this is not an API call either.

Below is the code I write in my functions.php to print the `$_POST` data that submitted from my another application. I used `shortcode` to view it in the front-page:

```
<?php
function view_post_data(){
echo"<pre>";print_r($_POST);    
}
add_shortcode( 'print_it', 'view_post_data' );
?>
```

Any best practice for this?

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.

Comment: Hi. Appreciate it if there's any advice on the question. Thanks!